# Retrieve Column By Header Name

Tags: c#, excel

I am using OLEDB to read the data from an Excel spreadsheet.

```
var connectionString =
  string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;", fileName);

var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [sheet1$]", connectionString);
var ds = new DataSet();

adapter.Fill(ds, "mySheet");
var data = ds.Tables["mySheet"].AsEnumerable();

foreach (var dataRow in data)
  { 
  Console.WriteLine(dataRow[0].ToString());                        
  }
```

Instead of passing an index to the DataRow to get the value of a column, is there anyway to retrieve the column by the name of the column header?

Comment: Have you tried LinqToExcel? https://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/

Comment: Where do you get the column headers? Is it the first row of the Excel sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
        var connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0; HDR=YES", fileName);

        var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [sheet1$]", connectionString);
        var ds = new DataSet();

        adapter.Fill(ds, "mySheet");
        var data = ds.Tables["mySheet"].AsEnumerable();

        foreach (DataRow dataRow in data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dataRow["MyColumnName"].ToString());    
            Console.WriteLine(dataRow.Field<string>("MyColumnName").ToString());
        }
```

I added in 2 ways to access the data in the row via column Name.

Hope this does the trick!!

Comment: Doh! Didn't try accessing by name. Thanks!!

Comment: What if my header strings are not in row 1? My Excel sheet starts with 3 empty rows and headers are at row 4.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your connection string to specify that you have headers in your excel file.

You can do this by setting the `HDR` value.

Refer this link to for various variations of connection string and build the one that suits your needs"

http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/

Answer (score 0):

Use a DataTable to have your data.

```
        string strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + **EXCEL FILE PATH** + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"";

        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
        conn.Open();            

        OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [**YOUR SHEET** $]", conn);
        cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        DataTable outputTable2 = new DataTable("myDataTable");

        new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd2).Fill(outputTable2);

        foreach(Datarow row in outputTable2)
        {
             String s = row["yourcolumnheader"].ToString();
        }
```