# How to get excel column name from datagridview

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, vba, datagridview

Hello guys i have a form application for renaming files which get data from excel and i want to get excel column names with datagridview what should i do?

edit:excel image on comments

```
path = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["K1"].Value.ToString();
            path2 = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["K2"].Value.ToString();
```

those K1 and K2 are the names of one of the excel column name, but i want it to work on all excel columns how it can be done?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication7
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            OleDbConnection baglan = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\STAJ\\AppData\\Roaming\\Skype\\My Skype Received Files\\ETKB-Aktarim-Test(1).xlsx ; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=YES;'");
            baglan.Open();
            string sorgu = "select * from [Sheet1$] ";
            OleDbDataAdapter data_adaptor = new OleDbDataAdapter(sorgu, baglan);
            baglan.Close();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            data_adaptor.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;


            string path="";
            string path2 = "";
            string newFileName = "";
            string oldFileName = "";
            int i = 0;


            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {


                try
                {
                    path = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["K1"].Value.ToString();
                    path2 = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["K2"].Value.ToString();
                    oldFileName = path ;
                    newFileName = path2;
                    if (File.Exists(oldFileName))
                    {
                        File.Move(oldFileName, newFileName);
                    }  
                  i++;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("DOSYA ADI DEGISTIRILDI");
    }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear what your goal is... can you post a screenshot of your Excel file? Are you trying to convert an Excel table with some headers to a datagridview, and give the dgv columns the name of the first row of that table?

Comment: @SpaceSteak no i want to get excel column names from c# no matter which excel file. It should work on all excels.That K1 and K2 are the excel columns name.

Comment: @SpaceSteak heres my excel http://i62.tinypic.com/4ios3t.jpg

Comment: the tinypic photo doesn't load... can you try imgur? Btw,  When you use HDR=Yes in Extended properties that assumes that your entire first row has column names... if K2 (instead of A1,B1) contains column names... are all Excel files you're going to import have the same format?  One thing I've done for this is ensure that all imported sheets have ranges with the titles and just use the range values for dgv column names... but this was using Excel.Workbook and not OleDb to load file.

Comment: @SpaceSteak http://imgur.com/6YzDMMj

Comment: ok I understand a bit better now. Can you try the solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20548039/retrieve-column-by-header-name ? basically each column should already have its header from the first row. put a breakpoint and look at the elements of your datatable... each row's columns should have an associated name. row.GetOrdinal("colNumber") might be able to get it